# Spring Boot returns 500 Internal Server Error instead of desired 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I am using `spring-security-web:5.6.3` to build a RESTful API. The API has a working authentication via Bearer tokens (JWT) and role-based authorization.

The problem is that when ever an authenticated user not not authorized to access a certain resource, the API returns a 500 error instead of a 403. Log output:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.<redacted>.<redacted>.api.controller.RedactedController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8274b324.getWorkInstructions(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.<redacted>.<redacted>.api.util.LogContextFilter.doFilter(LogContextFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at com.<redacted>.<redacted>.api.security.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.instrument.web.TraceWebServletConfiguration$LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletConfiguration.java:131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.tomcat.TraceValve.invoke(TraceValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I created a custom `AccessDeniedHandler` and wired it up in my `WebSecurityConfig`, but the error still persists. Can you verify my filtering order is correct?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private ApiUserDetailService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private ApiAccessDeniedHandler apiAccessDeniedHandler;

  @Autowired
  private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

  @Autowired
  private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new CustomPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authentication/*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api-docs").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api-docs/*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .accessDeniedHandler(apiAccessDeniedHandler)
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
}
```

ApiAccessDeniedHandler (a breakpoint on `response.sendError` will never be hit)

```
@Component
public class ApiAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Forbidden");
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/redacted")
@RolesAllowed({ROLE_1, ROLE_2, ROLE_3})
public class RedactedController {

  private final RedactedService redactedService;

  @Autowired
  public RedactedController(RedactedService service) {
    this.redactedService = service;
  }


  @GetMapping(path = "/entities")
  public ResponseEntity<PaginatedDTO<RedactedDTO>> getEntities(Pageable pageable) {
    Slice<RedactedDTO> entities = redactedService.getEntities(pageable);
    if (entities.getContent().size() == 0) {
      return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new PaginatedDTO<RedactedDTO>().fromSlice(entities));
  }
}
```

Comment: @zapl I added the (redacted) stack trace and the rest controller. It appears to me that the AccessDeniedException is thrown before the invocation of getEntities

Comment: What is your reason for a custom `AccessDeniedHandler`? The default implementation is exactly to send a 403, and there are built-in declarative options for the most common alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that I had a general ExceptionHandler in place:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {

  @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessageDTO> handleAllExceptions(Throwable t) {
    return ExceptionHandlerAdvice.handleNativeException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN,
            "Internal Server Error", t);
  }
}
```

This will disable Spring's default handling of the error and will only return a proper 403 error, if you explicitly tell it so:

```
  @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessageDTO> handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException e) {
    return handleNativeExceptionWithDetails(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, ErrorCodes.ACCESS_DENIED,
            "Access denied", e, false);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's good to understand how and when spring-security authorize users.

There are two main ways to configure user authorization with Spring security:

1. configuring `HttpSecurity` using `.antMatchers()` or similar methods
2. using annotations like `@Secured`, `@PreAuthorize`, `@RolesAllowed` at controller or service layer.

In the first case Spring checks roles and other authorization stuff **before** reaching controller, and here spring-security ***automatically translates*** insufficient authorization to 403 status code (unless you provide your custom `AccessDeniedHandler` implementation).
In the second case Spring tries to authorize user at controller or service layer and just throws `AccessDeniedException` in case of failure, so it's a developer's responsibility to catch it and translate into desired http response.

For example, if your code has something like `http.antMatchers("/product/**").hasRole("ADMIN")`, this rule will be checked in spring-security filters before executing controller method, and if the current user's role is not "ADMIN", you'll get 403 response automatically.

If you have `http.antMatchers("/product/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "CLIENT")`, and some method at service layer has `@Secured("ADMIN")` (without "CLIENT" role), *both rules will be checked*, but by different mechanisms.
So, if the current user's role is "CLIENT", user will be authorized at filter level and the controller method will be executed, but `AccessDeniedException` will be thrown at service layer, and you'll get 500 response if there's no `@ExceptionHandler` for it.